# How to remove "Show applications" button from dash in activities overview in gnome

Tags: gnome

In gnome, how do I remove the "Show Applications" button from activities overview (the menu that shows up when you press the super key) from the dash?

Comment: You can try this solution to hide the dock in the overview section https://askubuntu.com/a/1420078/1617229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the `hideShowApps.zip` file from github link https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/hide-showApps-button

[image]

from the downloaded location

```
gnome-extensions install hideShowApps.zip
gnome-extensions enable hideShowApps
```

restart the gnome-shell or logout and logback in

[image]

Comment: After entering this command I get `(false, '')` as output and the button is still there.

Comment: GNOME Shell 41.2
Apparently the "eval" interface is not available in this version anymore according to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/pneza1/gdbus_call_for_moving_windows_not_working_in/

Answer (score 0):

Fire up the terminal and type in

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-show-apps-button false`

Comment: I am not using dash to dock.